# Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with boundary conditions

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

I need to diagonalize(analytically) the following matrix(I really only need the eigenvalues):

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        a+e & -i x & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
        i x & a & -i x & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
        0 & ix & a & -ix & \cdots & 0\\
        0 & 0 & i x & a & \cdots & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots & -ix\\
        0 &  \cdots & 0 & 0  & ix & a-e
        \end{matrix}
$$

I'm not sure if this is too general of a problem to be solved, since this is equivalent to some boundary condition problems.

All constants are real, except for ix (which is purely imaginary).

From what I gathered the eigenvalues are of the form $\lambda = 2(1-\cos{\theta})$ but didn't manage to get much further.

There is a very similar question here:

[Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal matrix with special strucure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081633/eigenvalues-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix-with-special-strucure)

Answer (score 0):

Look at an article called:

Eigenvalues of Several Tridiagonal Matrices by Wen-ChyuanYueh.

The article has explained the development for tridiagonal matrices from first principles. The results are generalized for certain forms of tridiagonal matrices and I believe it has the solution for your case.